# Update shiny downloadHandler file path dynamically (eg. on button click)

Tags: r, shiny

Say on my Shiny app I have a download button that downloads files from the server directory 'out/'. However if I were to use the app to generate another file at 'out/report_fdgjwp.pdf' (filename randomly generated on the server) on the server, how would I update the file path in the downloadHandler? Currently it looks like the file path does not update through variables even when using a function for the pathname.

Here the original file path is declared with variables report_dir and report_name which are 'out/' and 'blank', respectively. A button click to the submit button updates the report_name variable to 'new_name', but clicking the download button after clicking the submit button does not change what report_name prints out within the downloadHandler. It also does not update the file path to 'out/new_name.pdf'

```
## in ui.R
  actionButton('submit', 'Submit'),
  downloadButton('download_report', 'Download')
```

```
## in server.R
  report_dir <- 'out/'
  report_name <- 'blank'

  submit_buttons <- reactive({
    req(isTruthy(input$submit))
  })

  observeEvent(submit_buttons(), {
    report_name <- 'new_name'
  })
  
  output$download_report <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste0('report_', Sys.Date(), '.pdf')
    },
    content = function(file) {
      print(report_name) ### returns 'blank' even after submit button is clicked
      file.copy(paste0(report_dir, report_name, '.pdf'), file)
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer was very simple... Use the super assignment operator <<- when updating server-level variables like report_name.

```
observeEvent(submit_buttons(), {
  report_name <<- 'new_name'
})
```

Using reactiveValues is also another solution.